# How to push JSX component into a Realm list data object?

Tags: react-native, realm, jsx, realm-list

For example, say I have a schema like this:

```
class ComponentSchema{};
ComponentSchema.schema = {
  name: 'Component',
  properties: {
    jsx: 'What goes here?'
  }
}

class ContainerSchema{};
ContainerSchema.schema = {
  name: 'JSXComponents',
  properties: {
    components: {type: 'list', objectType: 'Component'}
  }
}
```

Is there a way to push components into the `JSXComponents.components` list such that it can store something that represents:

```
{0: {jsx: <Component/>}, 1: {jsx: <OtherComponent/>}}
```

If there isn't a specific data type for JSX components, is there maybe a workaround?